# What is the two-item list equivalent of the Oxford comma?

Tags: oxford-comma

I was recently told that the Oxford comma is only for lists with three or more items. A preliminary search confirms this, as far as I can tell. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent word for a comma in a list with only two items, or if that's universally considered inappropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma between two items in a list (e.g. "War, and Peace") is grammatically incorrect.
(Correction: There are some rare instances in which this comma may be acceptable, according to this article: https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_the_Oxford_comma.htm.)